# How do I get to the last survival cache in the east Soviet Installation?

Tags: rise-of-the-tomb-raider

I tried backtracking both ways to this area and hit a wall.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You likely haven't been to this area before. Later in the story, you will automatically [unlock a nearly base camp](https://youtu.be/0LACq9sfdKw?t=16m12s) (Copper Mill Bridge), so if you're unable to return to this spot, you haven't sufficiently advanced in the story.